# New way to drop and recreate database schema in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

For some unit tests I'm dropping and recreating the entire database schema after each test. Its not perfect but it works. However when I upgraded from Spring 3.0.6 to 3.1.0.RC2 to get support for Hibernate 4, the methods I was using got deleted.

Old code:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setupSchema() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean session = (LocalSessionFactoryBean) context.getBean("&sessionFactory");
    session.dropDatabaseSchema();
    session.createDatabaseSchema();
}
```

what am I supposed to use instead to recreate the database schema in 3.1.0.RC2?

**EDIT:** Note that this is for the hibernate4 LocalSessionFactoryBean, not the hibernate3 one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those interested, fixed this problem today. Essentially just use SchemaExport

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setupSchema() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean session = (LocalSessionFactoryBean) context.getBean("&sessionFactory");
    SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(session.getConfiguration());
    export.drop(false, true);
    export.create(false, true);
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

[JavaDoc for 3.1.0 RC2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/)

The methods still exist in this. However, also notice there is two LocalSessionFactoryBean's in the java doc(see left hand side scroll list)!!

[EDIT] As mentioned below the methods have been  deprecated in hibernate 4

Comment: Actually if you look carefully there's one for hibernate3 and one for hibernate4. I'm using the one for hibernate4. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In recent Spring with Hibernate 5, dropping the database works as follows:

```java
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

...

var localSessionFactoryBean = applicationContext.getBean(LocalSessionFactoryBean.class);
var schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
schemaExport.drop(EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE), 
    localSessionFactoryBean.getMetadataSources().buildMetaData());
```